# How to iterate over a JSON array and get values for a key which itself is a JSON object

Tags: python, json, iterator

I have been trying to do something simple yet something hard for me to solve it!

I have a json object that looks like:

```
   jsonObject =  {
      'attributes': {
        '192': { <--- This can be changed times to times meaning different number
          'id': '192',
          'code': 'hello',
          'label': 'world',
          'options': [
            {
              'id': '211',
              'label': '5'
            },
            {
              'id': '1202',
              'label': '8.5'
            },
            {
              'id': '54',
              'label': '9'
            },
            {
              'id': '1203',
              'label': '9.5'
            },
            {
              'id': '58',
              'label': '10'
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      'template': '12345',
      'basePrice': '51233',
      'oldPrice': '51212',
      'productId': 'hello',
    }
```

and what I want to do is to get the values from options (To have both id and label saved into a list)

For now I only managed to do:

```
for att, value in jsonObject.items():
     print(f"{att} - {value}"
```

How can I get the label and id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```py
attr = jsonObject['attributes']
temp = list(attr.values())[0]  # It is same as "temp = attr['192']", but you said '192' can be changed.
options = temp['options']
for option in options:
    print(f"id: {option['id']}, label: {option['label']}")
```

Comment: I love you! Was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I guess you can also short it down to `for option in list(attributes['attributes'].values())[0]['options']:`

Comment: Appreciate it however! Was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie Oh, I found a mistake in your comment. It should be `for option in list(jsonObject['attributes'].values())[0]['options']:`

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie No problem :) Happy programming!